# How to constrain the maximum distance between the highest and lowest values?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

Suppose I have an $1 \times 10$ array of discrete binary decision variables of price points, where:

- $0$ = do not use this price point
- $1$ = use this price point

and that any number of price points can be selected. For example, $[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]$ means that $1$, $4$, $7$, and $10$ are selected.

**How do I add a constraint in Excel Solver such that the distance between the largest and smallest price points is less than or equal to cell I enter?**

For instance, if I enter in $5$ in the "Maximum Price Spread" cell:

```
A: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] violates constraint
B: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] meets constraint
```

I would need to construct a constraint in Solver such that [A] cannot happen because the distance between $1$ and $10$ is not $\leq 5$ maximum spread.

The decision array [B] would meet the constraint since the highest value, $8$, less the lowest value, $3 = 5 \leq 5$ maximum spread.

The problem is stumping me because the constraint needs to be set up whilst remaining linear. For example, MAX() and MIN() cannot be used to evaluate changing cells values because it would result in a discontinuous function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I don't get what you mean.  In the 2nd paragrah, you say $[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]$ is OK, but in the last paragraph, $[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]$ is not.  What do you mean by OK?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I assume the last paragraph to be console input/output, so it's alright to use monospaced font.

Comment: @GNU Supporter: 
I edited the example for clarity. Thank you for your feedback. In the above, the array of binary decision variables [A] would violate the constraint. [B] would meet the constraint.

Comment: Duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497437/excel-solver-linear-programming-how-to-set-constraint-enforcing-the-maximum

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following constraint:
$$
\max_{i,j} \; |ix_i - jx_j| \le \delta
$$
where $x_i$ are your binaries and $\delta$ your limit. Of course, you need to linearize this constraint, for example as follows:
\begin{align}
&z \le \delta \\
&z \ge ix_i - jx_j \quad \forall i,j \\
&z \ge jx_j - ix_i \quad \forall i,j
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! May I ask what z is in this case? Is it another floating decision variable?

Comment: Yes it is an extra variable used for linearization

Comment: If I hard-code*** constraints for a base case where the limit = \$6, then I have a optimized solution at [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]. The highest price is \$8 and the lowest price is \$2.

For i = 8, j = 0, then the second constraint looks like = (\$8)(1) - (\$1)(0) = \$8. But there is no feasible solution where z >= \$8 and z <= \$7.

***(by restricting pairs such as \$1, \$8 such that their binaries sum to no more than 1)

Comment: Thank you both for your input (and on the other thread as well). I think I know why Solver cannot find a solution for either case. With $[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]$, $maxprice = 8*1, minprice = 0$, and $maxdifference = 8 - 0 = 8$. Yet the intended difference is 6, not 8, thus the constraints make the base case infeasible.

Comment: This is $n^2$. A formulation with $2n$ constraints is $$\begin{align} &maxprice \ge x_i p_i\\
 &minprice \le x_i p_i + M (1-x_i)\\ &maxprice−minprice\le \mathit{maxdifference}\end{align}$$ where $M=max_i p_i$, this is a constant  (I forgot earlier the $M$ construct).

Comment: Thank you both, @ErwinKalvelagen solution worked.